Asslamu alaykum wa rahhmantullilahi wa barakathu
so basically im starting Dawah with some Akhis in Czech we allready have some knowleage and are ready but ill be happy if someone will give me more usefull verses and things to dawah that will revert as many people as its possible  with your help you will also get rewarded for this InshaAllah  theres some questions thats are common and i would want you brothers/sisters to answer to them ( ik the answers but many others here are surely gonna do it better and make it easier for us ) thank you and JazakAllah .
